# Deploying CI application on dreamhost subdomain, site not redirecting to the default controller issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have deployed a CI application to dreamhost in a subdomain.

The application does not seem to redirect to the default_controller in the config. file.

Eg. www.example.ex.com does not redirect to www.example.ex.com/home

**my config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.ex.com';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

$config['url_suffix'] = '';
```

**my routes.php**

```
 $route['default_controller'] = "home";
```

**my .htaccess **

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks in advance. Any help much appreciated. :)

Comment: What happens if you DIRECTLY go to www.example.ex.com/home ?

Comment: it works if i go directly to that. but it does not redirect automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set it in `$route['default_controller'] = "home"` your controller should just be loaded in the page but NOT be shown in the URL.

If I got your question right I think you should just use

```
redirect('home');
```

This will actually make your browser go to that page; while the `$route['default_controller'] = "home"` just loads the controller without showing it up in the URL.

Comment: the problem is if i directly go to www.example.ex.com/home it works and if i just go to www.example.ex.com it gives a 404 !

Comment: I see, edit your answer so that this is specified. Can you post the header of the home controller? (Everything up to the index() function?